# formatting numbers as text in excel

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Building an excel spreadsheet is a classic asp application.  The problem now is that one of the columns is being automatically formatted by excel as a number when it should really be text and so it is removing leading zeros which the boss wants to keep.  I have done some web search and you should be able to pre-append an apostrophe to the string forcing excel to display it as text:

```
If isNumeric(val) Then
response.write "'" & val
Else
response.write val
End If
```

Great, but excel is now displaying those columns with a leading apostrophe!  From the reading that I have done the leading apostrophe should be hidden and only used by excel as formatting, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If I wrap it in double quotes it displays those as well.  I think one of the issues is that the column is a varchar and some of the cells contain text such as 'web' and this may be 'confusing' excel some what!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little poking around I found this to work:

```
Response.Write "=""" & Trim(val) & """"
```

Displayed correctly and the formatting characters were not displayed, unless of course  you click on the cell then the contents is displayed in the header.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the Excel by using Microsoft Libraries, instead of creating csv file that Excel reads.  Then you can basically specify the column as a Text.  By doing so you don't have to add string characters into the cell.

Comment: The code is something like .Range(A:A).Format ... where you are formatting column A.

Comment: Not using the libraries, older page creating a table but sending the headers as a .xls file.  Not my original code just tasked with making it work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **white space** character in HTML `&nbsp;` before the value you want to insert in the Excel cell:

```
If isNumeric(val) Then
    response.write "&nbsp;" & val
Else
    response.write val
End If
```