# How can I write 001 into Excel instead of 1

Tags: excel, vbscript, formatting, numbers

I write the following line into Excel file from my VBscript code

```
excelFile.write("001"  & vbTab)
```

But when I check the excel it has value `1` instead of `001`

How can I convince excel to "not helping me" from VBscript?

I cannot change all of the user's excel. I need do it from **VBScript**.

When I write into txt file the number is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [formatting numbers as text in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595652/formatting-numbers-as-text-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved my problem

```
excelFile.write("="""001""""  & vbTab)
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595652/formatting-numbers-as-text-in-excel):

Answer (score 1):

As you mention a text file, I believe execFile is a text stream that writes a tab delimited file that is imported into Excel later. Then you should quote (all) the data in (all) the text columns:

```
excelFile.write """001"""  & vbTab
```

You may have to state this in the import specification and/or in a schema.ini file.

Comment: is just write the contect into a file eg: fstemp.CreateTextFile(filename, true)

but the not helped """001""" also

Answer (score 1):

'Firstly in Excel select entire column right click and select Format Cells, 'Custom and enter 000

'vbscript to make any cell in column A format 000 would be as follows

```
enter code here
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible =False
Set wb1 = xl.WorkBooks.Open("c:\Test.xls")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
xl.columns("A:A").NUMBERFORMAT="000"
wb1.Save
xl.displayalerts=false
xl.Quit 
Set wb1 = nothing
Set xl = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of the cell that you're writing into from 'General' to 'Custom' '000' - This will give you 3 digits to any number you enter

If you need to do it from VB itself you should be able to do something like:

```
 Cells.Select 

    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "000"
    End With
```

Comment: I cannot change all of the user's excel.
I need do it from VBScript.

Comment: I need do it from VBScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
excelFile.write("'001")
```

I just put `'` before the first 0.